less on MacOS and zsh not showing colors
Solved, problem was in ls binary, that I replaced with (for some unknown reason) and its colorizing options are different to ls. However, leaving this post since it contains very useful debugging tips.
am using zsh as shell on MacOS Sequoia and iTerm2. When I pipe anything that has color output to less, it does not show with colors. As test I was using:
CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -G | less -R

When I start bash and execute same command it works, less shows all colors. I presume it is some shell setting but I cannot find which one.
I inspected both .zprofile and .zshrc, nothing there that can point me to solution. I also check bash configuration files but nothing significant in them either. Any idea how to solve this?
Some extra information as requested:
dj.dule@Mac ~ % type ls less; env | grep -e LESS -e COLOR -e LS -e TERM
ls is /bin/ls
less is /opt/homebrew/bin/less
TERM_SESSION_ID=w0t3p0:C5B2EB8A-6F45-430E-908E-45F848BB1FD8
LC_TERMINAL_VERSION=3.5.5
COLORFGBG=7;0
ITERM_PROFILE=Default
TERM_FEATURES=T3LrMSc7UUw9Ts3BFGsSyHNoSxF
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=3.5.5
TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app
LC_TERMINAL=iTerm2
COLORTERM=truecolor
TERM=xterm-256color
TERMINFO_DIRS=/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Resources/terminfo:/usr/share/terminfo
ITERM_SESSION_ID=w0t3p0:C5B2EB8A-6F45-430E-908E-45F848BB1FD8
LESSOPEN=| /opt/homebrew/bin/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s
LESS= -R

Essentially the same in bash:
dj.dule@Mac ~ % bash
bash-5.2$ type ls less; env | grep -e LESS -e COLOR -e LS -e TERM
ls is /bin/ls
less is /opt/homebrew/bin/less
ITERM_PROFILE=Default
COLORTERM=truecolor
LESS= -R
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=3.5.5
TERM_FEATURES=T3LrMSc7UUw9Ts3BFGsSyHNoSxF
TERM_SESSION_ID=w0t3p0:C5B2EB8A-6F45-430E-908E-45F848BB1FD8
ITERM_SESSION_ID=w0t3p0:C5B2EB8A-6F45-430E-908E-45F848BB1FD8
LC_TERMINAL=iTerm2
TERM=xterm-256color
LESSOPEN=| /opt/homebrew/bin/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s
COLORFGBG=7;0
LC_TERMINAL_VERSION=3.5.5
TERMINFO_DIRS=/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Resources/terminfo:/usr/share/terminfo
TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app

printf '\e[31mTest\e[m\n' | less -R do show red Test in both bash and zsh. Same in bash --norc and zsh -f, all combinations work properly and show red.
It seems it is happening when piping to other commands as well in zsh, but not in bash:
dj.dule@air-m2 ~ % CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -G | hexdump -C                                                                                                                   [0]
00000000  61 64 61 72 73 68 2e 70  70 6b 0a 41 70 70 6c 69  |adarsh.ppk.Appli|
00000010  63 61 74 69 6f 6e 73 0a  43 61 6c 69 62 72 65 20  |cations.Calibre |
...

bash-3.2$ CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -G | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 33 34 6d 41 70 70  6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e  |.[34mApplication|
00000010  73 1b 5b 33 39 3b 34 39  6d 1b 5b 30 6d 0a 1b 5b  |s.[39;49m.[0m..[|
00000020  33 34 6d 43 61 6c 69 62  72 65 20 4c 69 62 72 61  |34mCalibre Libra|

tput colors in both shells returns 256

Does printf '\e[31mTest\e[m\n' | less -R show a red Test in both bash and zsh? How about if you run your pipeline in bash --norc and zsh -f?

The bash --norc and zsh -f request was more for your pipeline, so we can check whether things in the startup files affect the behaviour of ls/less or the terminal emulator.

Solved, problem was in ls binary, that I replaced with (for some unknown reason) and its colorizing options are different to ls. However, leaving this post since it contains very useful debugging tips.
